# Trying to count distinct users in mysql using partition by

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I am trying to get a count of distinct users in a database by day. My data is in a local mysql database and this partition by code isn't giving me the count I need.

```
select date(created) as created_at,
count(distinct user_id) over (PARTITION by date(created)) as ytd_count 
from testdb.request_log;
```

SQL Workbench is giving me a syntax error at (P.

Please help?

Comment: MySQL does not support window/analytic functions.

Comment: I tried that. What I am trying to get is something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select date(created) as created_at, count(distinct user_id) as ytd_count
from testdb.request_log
group by date(created);
```

MySQL does not support window/analytic functions.  In this case, though, I think an aggregation does what you want.